# Spring HashMap value-ref Key points to value ref name

Tags: spring, hashmap

Here is my HashMap in spring context which uses value-ref :

```
<util:map id="generalDAOMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="1" value-ref="userDAO" />
        <entry key="2" value-ref="accountsDAO" />
        <entry key="3" value-ref="settingsDAO" />       
</util:map>
<bean id="userDAO"
        class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl" />
<bean id="accountsDAO"
        class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.AccountsDAOImpl" />
<bean id="settingsDAO"
        class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.SettingsDAOImpl" />
```

In my Java class i have autowired the "generalDAOMap" as below:

```
@AutoWired

private Map<String,GeneralDAO> generalDAOMap;

//getters and setters follows
```

When i print the map value its as follows :

```
{userDAO = com.test.myproj.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl@164d6ae,accountsDAO = com.test.myproj.dao.impl.AccountsDAOImpl@ed9382 , settingsDAO = com.test.myproj.dao.impl.SettingsDAOImpl@ed9586}
```

but the Key values should be "1","2" and "3" , why its getting replaced as "userDAO ","settingsDAO " and "accountsDAO ", due to which when i use getGeneralDAOMap.get("1") it returns null. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using `@Resource` instead of using `@Autowired` ?

[Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) says this,

> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection or map bean by unique name.

Comment: FYI i was fighting with this not working until i figured that, as above, the id of the map bean needs to match the map property name. Are you aware of any documentation for it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try ...

```
    <util:map id="generalDAOMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
            <entry key="1"> 
               <bean class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl" />
            </entry>       
            <entry key="2">
              <bean class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.AccountsDAOImpl" />
            </entry>       
            <entry key="3">
              <bean class="com.test.myproj.dao.impl.SettingsDAOImpl" /> 
            </entry>       
    </util:map>
```

Comment: Still the same error null ... now map content has nothing to print.